# How to check if particular files from list of filenames present in directory with regex or grep in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, file, grep

need to write a script to check if a specific files list are present or not in a directory

files in directory /dir look_like

ABC_YYYYMMDD_EF.txt 
GHI_YYYYMMDD_LM.txt

and list has names like

> l=[ABC_EF, GHI_LM,PQR_ST,..]

so have to ignore YYYYMMDD which can be anydate in this format ,can anyone tell should we use grep or regex and how
like output: \

```
ABC_EF   FOUND
GHI_LM   FOUND
PQR_ST   NOT FOUND
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your question. Right now the formatting is making it hard to understand what you're trying to do. Also clarify what you mean by `list has names like ...` - what "list", where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

dir="$1"

names=( ABC_EF GHI_LM PQR_ST )
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    files=( "${dir}/${name%_*}_"+([0-9])"_${name#*_}.txt" )
    (( ${#files[@]} )) && result="" || result="NOT "
    printf '%s\t%sFOUND\n' "$name" "$result"
done
```

```
$ ls tmp
ABC_19001231_EF.txt  GHI_20200102_LM.txt
```

```
$ ./tst.sh tmp
ABC_EF  FOUND
GHI_LM  FOUND
PQR_ST  NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v lst="ABC_EF,GHI_LM,PQR_ST" '
    BEGIN { 
            split(lst,map,",") # split the passed variable lst in an array map, using the function split and the delimiter ,
          } 
    END { 
            for (i in map) { # Loop through each entry in the map array
                             split(map[i],map1,"_"); # Further split the map values in map1 using _ as the delimiter
                             res=""; # Initialise a res variable
                             "find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex \"^.*"map1[1]"_.*[[:digit:]]+.*_"map1[2]".txt\"" | getline res; # Execute a find command and register the result in res using getline
                             if (res !="") { 
                                             print map[i]" FOUND" # If res is not empty, print FOUND, otherwise NOT FOUND.
                                           } 
                                      else { 
                                             print map[i]" NOT FOUND"
                                            } 
                              close("find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex \"^.*"map1[1]"_[[:digit:]]{8}_"map1[2]".txt\"") # Close the pipe
                              } 
                            }' <<< /dev/null
```

One liner:

```
awk -v lst="ABC_EF,GHI_LM,PQR_ST" 'BEGIN { split(lst,map,",") } END { for (i in map) { split(map[i],map1,"_");res="";"find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex \"^.*"map1[1]"_.*[[:digit:]]+.*_"map1[2]".txt\"" | getline res;if (res !="") { print map[i]" FOUND" } else { print map[i]" NOT FOUND"} close("find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex \"^.*"map1[1]"_[[:digit:]]{8}_"map1[2]".txt\"") } }' <<< /dev/null
```

Comment: Hi Raman thank you so much for your efforts, but I think there is some minute error in regex expression , still it is printing not found for every file even if it is present

Comment: Can you add the exact files you have in the directory that should be found?

Comment: I tested this by creating GHI_20201220_LM.txt and  ABC_20201204_EF.txt and so it showed two as found and one as not found.

Comment: I've changed the regular expression to take account of different format dates.